# How to treat a shape painted with an algorithm like an object?

Tags: java, graphics, paint

Ok dear folks, i've got this question and i don't really know a certain way to solve it.
I'm doing like a "Paint application" in java, i know everything is ready, but I need to paint the shapes with Computer Graphics Algorithms.

So, the thing is, once the shape is painted in the container how could I convert it like sort of an "Object" to be able to select the shape and move it around (I have to move it with another algorithm) I just want to know how could I know that some random point clicked in the screen belongs to an object, knowing that, I would be able to fill it(with algorithm).

I was thinking that having a Point class, and a shape class, if i click on the screen, get the coordinates and look within all the shapes and their points, but this may not be very efficient.
Any ideas guys ? 
Thanks for the help.
Here is some of my code:

```
public class Windows extends JFrame{

private JPanel panel;
private JLabel etiqueta,etiqueta2;
public Windows() {
    initcomp();
}
public void initcomp()
{
    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 300);
    etiqueta = new JLabel("Circulo Trigonometrico");
    etiqueta.setBounds(20, 40, 200, 30);
    etiqueta2 = new JLabel("Circulo Bresenham");
    etiqueta2.setBounds(150, 110, 200, 30);

    panel.setLayout(null);
    panel.add(etiqueta);
    panel.add(etiqueta2);
    panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
this.add(panel);
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setSize(400,400);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
       Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
       g2d.setColor(Color.red);
       g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));

       dibujarCirculo_bresenham(g2d, 50, 260, 260);
       dibujarCirculo_trigonometrico(g2d, 50, 130, 200);
}
/*This functions paints a Circle*/
public void dibujarCirculo_trigonometrico(Graphics g,int R,int xc,int yc)
{

      int x,y;
      for (int i = 0; i < 180; i++) {
        double angulo = Math.toRadians(i);
        x = (int) (Math.cos(angulo)*R);
        y = (int) (Math.sin(angulo)*R);
        g.drawLine(x+xc, y+yc, x+xc, y+yc);
        g.drawLine((-x+xc), (-y+yc), (-x+xc), (-y+yc));
    }
 }
```

Comment: Write each CG algorithm into it's own object, with properties like location and size, which you can then control as you need.  These could be extending from something like `JPanel` or self contained to your "drawing" container which knows how to interact with them

Comment: I tried this and got this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at Lienzo.initcomp(Lienzo.java:30)
 at Lienzo.<init>(Lienzo.java:14)
 at Lienzo.main(Lienzo.java:42)

Comment: Without the source, its impossible to suggest a possible solution

Answer (score 0):

I assume that any image is a valid (isn't constrained to a particular set of shapes). To get an contiguous area with similar properties, try using a [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill).

[image]

To colour in or move a particular shape around, you can use flood fill to determine the set of pixels and manipulate the set accordingly. You can set a tolerance for similar hue, etc so that it's not as rigid as in Paint, and becomes more like the magic selection tool in Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to take here depending on what precisely you want.

1) is to have objects, one for each drawn thing on screen, with classes like Circle and Rectangle and Polygon so on. They would define methods like paint (how to draw them on screen), isCLickInsideOf (is a click at this point on screen contained by this shape, given size/position/etc?) and so on. Then, to redraw the screen draw each object, and to test if an object is being clicked on ask each object what it thinks.

2) is, if objects have the property of being uniform in colour, you can grab all pixels that make up a shape when the user clicks on one of the pixels by using a floodfill algorithm. Then you can load these into some kind of data structure, move them around as the user moves the mouse around, etc. Also, if every object is guaranteed to have a unique colour, you can test which object is being clicked on by just looking at colour. (Libraries like OpenGL use a trick like this sometimes to determine what object you have clicked on - drawing each object as a flat colour on a hidden frame and testing what pixel colour under the mouse pointer is)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried the first option creating a common class called Figure (extending from jpanel), and other class called Circle, But i can't add this object to my JPanel,i get this error.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
 at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
 at Lienzo.initcomp(Lienzo.java:30)
 at Lienzo.<init>(Lienzo.java:14)
 at Lienzo.main(Lienzo.java:42)
So, how can i add my object to my JPanel?

Comment: @user2430929 Check for nulls in your code (all variables are null by default, and all array entries are null by default)